# SharePoint development and SpecFlow on the same machine?

Tags: sharepoint, specflow

I need some guidance on how to have SpecFlow installed on my Visual Studio 2010 development machine which is also leveraged for SharePoint 2010 development.

The .feature extensions causes some bad behavior...

Comment: Like what? Crashes? Dialogs? Messages? A little bit more context is needed...

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a version of SpecFlow that resolves this issue.  You can get more info in [this post](http://www.hreyes.net/using-specflow-in-sharepoint-solutions/).

What I had to do to resolve the issue was download the source and change the extension for the feature files to .sfeature.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here might be that SharePoint 2010 and SpecFlow make use of the `.feature` file extension. I did some research into this and found a SpecFlow Google group query about a similar problem. The answer given to the user with the problem was:

> Hi,  I'm sure you know the SharePoint
>   project better then me. Do you see 
>   any conceptual idea how this conflict
>   could be resolved? What parts  are
>   conflicting, the syntax coloring or
>   the generation? Is the  SharePoint
>   ".feature" file can also be placed in
>   a normal c#/vbnet  project?
>
> Tips for
>   manual workarounds:  to switch off the
>   automatic recognition of the .feature
>   file for the 
>   *genrator*: 
>   - rename key ".feature" to ".featureX" at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE 
>   \Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Generators{FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-
>   BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}.feature" (this is
>   for C# projects)
>
> - you can still set the generation manually in VS by specifying 
>     "SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator" for the
>     "custom tool" property of the  file 
>     to switch off syntax coloring:
> - remove (or rename) the shortcut at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual 
>     Studio
>     10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TechTalk\SpecFlow
>     Br,  Gaspar

Maybe you could try the registry hack mentioned above and that might let you use SPecFLow with SharePoint?

The original thread can be found here:

http://groups.google.com/group/specflow/browse_thread/thread/4e6a80f3aa3624c2?pli=1